# Java app failing to launch on Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: java

I run a commercial Java app as a development environment on Mac OS Sierra. The version I am running is no longer supported. That said, there is a minor upgrade available for this version 7.0.1->7.0.3. But I have never been able to run it. I ran the installer and went to launch the app and it fails to launch.

I thought I could see if I could find the error through the Java console or through a verbose launch or similar. I can't seem to view the Java console even though it is marked as 'Show' in the Java Control Panel.

In the OS Console I get:

```
Nov  6 00:57:59 waynesmacbook TeraScribe7[28034]: assertion failed: 16G1510: libxpc.dylib + 74307 [ABC3BB29-BCE6-3E50-8A71-4E56AEE28991]: 0x89
Nov  6 00:59:46 waynesmacbook TeraScribe7[28416]: assertion failed: 16G1510: libxpc.dylib + 74307 [ABC3BB29-BCE6-3E50-8A71-4E56AEE28991]: 0x89
Nov  6 01:04:27 waynesmacbook com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.lateragent[612]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by loginwindow[119]
Nov  6 01:11:01 waynesmacbook TeraScript Server 7[107]: START      WARNING  Cannot retrieve the machine name, using localhost (127.0.0.1) instead
Nov  6 01:13:51 waynesmacbook TeraScribe7[770]: assertion failed: 16G1618: libxpc.dylib + 74307 [ABC3BB29-BCE6-3E50-8A71-4E56AEE28991]: 0x89
```

When I try to launch from Terminal I get:

```
------Executable: cd "/Applications/TeraScribe 7"; "/Applications/TeraScribe 7/jre/bin/java" -Xms268435456 -Xmx1073741824 -cp "/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/../wds6.jar:/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lax.jar:/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/Resources/Java/linking.zip" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.library.path=.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:"/Applications/TeraScribe 7":"/Applications/TeraScribe 7/jre/lib":"/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/Resources/Java":"/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/MacOS":"/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/Resources" -Xdock:name="TeraScribe" -Xdock:icon="/Applications/TeraScribe 7/TeraScribe.app/Contents/Resources/LaunchAnywhere.icns" com.zerog.lax.LAX "/var/folders/bx/prgb3chn2ml5lxfd_xt_7hlw0000gr/T/app.properties"-------

java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: waynesmacbook.byteserve.com.au: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Another instance of this application is already running.  Exiting.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I have spoken to the supplier but their answer is 'Upgrade to V8'. That is a $3000 upgrade. Running out of options to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try rebooting? *Another instance of this application is already running.  Exiting.* why would this be ? is it a daemon?

Comment: Strangely, after posting this question I tried installing it on a new install of Sierra with Java and it ran fine. I then quit and tried to restart and it exhibited the same issue.

Thinking this might be an issue with quitting and leaving a process open I restarted and tried again. Same issue.

I did notice is Activity Monitor (sorta like Top) that when you launch the app it loads two process then quits.